# How do I keep changes made within a python GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, interactive

For, example If a button click turns the background blue, or changes the button's text, how do I make sure that change stays even after i go to other frames?

Comment: If you have not written the code for it to change, why will it change then?

Answer (score 0):

One way to go is to create a configuration file (e.g. `conf.ini`) where you store your changes or apply them to other dialogs. It will allow you to keep changes after an app restarted.

Comment: Thank you! But I've never used any configuration functions before. Could you give an example of how to use them, or have any links on introduction to using it?

Comment: @Shoba you can simply use writing string to file and then read them as usual. Anytime you'll be able to refactor this functionality